# magento is not showing cart products on some pages

Tags: cart

Magento cart showing products on cart and main page correctly, but it is showing empty cart on categories and product pages, actually cart is not empty.

My site cache is disable. My site is `dressat.se` Please help me.

Comment: have you used any external modules on your website ? I think this is ultimo theme you are using for website.

Comment: Looks like a Varnish wrong configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please not ask your question multiple times. You posted your question also yesterday. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16089/magento-is-not-showing-cart-products-on-just-categories-and-product-pages/16093#16093

Comment: But I have to find solution, therefor I have asked again.

Comment: Yes Dexter I am using some external modules, like onepage checkout, payson payment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like this was a Varnish caching issue. It seems to be working now, as the category and product page are showing a response header of:
X-Cache:SGCACHE-MISS

My guess is the cart part of the page was not properly hole punched and was being cached incorrectly via a Varnish plugin or manual Varnish installation.

Comment: A lot of thanks for this tip. For me, also, after stop Varnish Cache, disappears this problem with empty cart.